# Large sql table using last_value+over

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

First of all, I'm not a DBA and this post my contain some *ugly* sql code. :)

**Context**

I have a table that represents all my product stock activities (in the SQL "TP_MOVI"), since the beginning of the process through the end of it. Following this line, one product (in the SQL "CODIGO") may have balance in multiple places (in the SQL "ARMAZEM").

In the table, I have all types of activities and my job is summarize it, for example, a balance of all products until the current date or a parametrized date. My logic about that was to get the last record of all products+place by using the clause `LAST_VALUE() OVER()`), generating a balance of all the places.

My table currently has over than 1 000 000 records, and right now, it causes some interruptions while I'm trying to retrieve data from this table and, of course, delaying on retrieving the data.
I'm pretty sure my SQL code is incorrect and it's causing this problem, could you guys help me out to get this code better?

I've been reading something about the statement `WITH NO LOCK`, will it help?

**Content - SQL Code**

```
CREATE TABLE [MOVIMENTACOES](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DATA] [datetime] NULL,
    [CODIGO] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [ARMAZEM] [int] NULL,
    [TP_MOVI] [varchar](10),
    [QUANTIDADE] [float] NULL,
    [SALDO] [float] NULL,
    [ATV] [bit] NULL)

INSERT INTO [MOVIMENTACOES]([DATA],[CODIGO],[ARMAZEM],[TP_MOVI],[QUANTIDADE],[SALDO],[ATV])VALUES('2017-04-24 05:54:59.340','123456',18,'PROD',0,10,1)
INSERT INTO [MOVIMENTACOES]([DATA],[CODIGO],[ARMAZEM],[TP_MOVI],[QUANTIDADE],[SALDO],[ATV])VALUES('2017-04-24 05:54:59.340','123456',18,'PROD',10,15,1)
INSERT INTO [MOVIMENTACOES]([DATA],[CODIGO],[ARMAZEM],[TP_MOVI],[QUANTIDADE],[SALDO],[ATV])VALUES('2017-04-24 05:54:59.340','456789',19,'PROD',0,20,1)
INSERT INTO [MOVIMENTACOES]([DATA],[CODIGO],[ARMAZEM],[TP_MOVI],[QUANTIDADE],[SALDO],[ATV])VALUES('2017-04-24 05:54:59.340','456789',19,'PROD',20,15,1)
INSERT INTO [MOVIMENTACOES]([DATA],[CODIGO],[ARMAZEM],[TP_MOVI],[QUANTIDADE],[SALDO],[ATV])VALUES('2017-04-24 05:54:59.340','123456',28,'PROD',0,6,1)
INSERT INTO [MOVIMENTACOES]([DATA],[CODIGO],[ARMAZEM],[TP_MOVI],[QUANTIDADE],[SALDO],[ATV])VALUES('2017-04-24 05:54:59.340','123456',28,'SALE',6,-6,1)

SELECT 
    MOV.ID,
    MOV.DATA, MOV.CODIGO, MOV.ARMAZEM, MOV.TP_MOVI,
    MOV.SALDO,
    MOV.QUANTIDADE,
    MOV.SALDO + LAST_VALUE(MOV.QUANTIDADE) OVER(ORDER BY MOV.DATA ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS SALDO_ACUMULADO
FROM MOVIMENTACOES MOV

    LEFT OUTER JOIN MOVIMENTACOES MOV2 ON
        MOV2.CODIGO = MOV.CODIGO AND        
        MOV2.ARMAZEM = MOV.ARMAZEM AND
        MOV2.ID > MOV.ID
        AND MOV2.DATA <= '2017-04-25 07:00:00'
WHERE
    MOV2.ID IS NULL
    AND MOV.DATA <= '2017-04-25 07:00:00'
```

Here are the schema and some example of the data: http://rextester.com/XIXCB97220

Comment: The NOLOCK hint is not a performance tool that comes without some serious baggage. It can help performance slightly but comes at a cost for accuracy. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/ I don't think it would help you at all here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Sean! I'll check the link.
Could you think about something to help me to improve this query?

Comment: Can you give us the Query Plan associated with your query ?
This way we will be able to analyse what is time consuming in your request exactly and how to increase performance.

Comment: Just something that I noted in the query `MOV2.ID > MOV.ID` and `MOV2.ID IS NULL` seems to not correlate with each other.

Comment: What is the outer join used for? Used with `IS NULL` it's usually similar to a `NOT EXISTS`. And in your case you might be able to remove it and use another window-function instead.

Comment: And your `LAST_VALUE` returns exactly the same as a simple `MOV.QUANTIDADE`.

Comment: @Hybris95: Here's the query plan: http://imgur.com/a/f4MtM
I saw that hash match was the top cost and attached it too.

Comment: @Joby: To be sure with you, I've researched how to iterate through the column "ARMAZEM" dynamically and it was the way that worked.

Comment: @dnoeth: Same as I told to Joby, I found something similar to my needs and tried to adapt. It was something almost like a banking account.

Comment: So waht exactly are you trying to do? And what's your SQL Server version?

Comment: @dnoeth: I need exactly as the output here: http://rextester.com/XIXCB97220
The balance with CODIGO+ARMAZEM dynamically, in the example I put just 3 types "ARMAZEM" but as I said it need to be dynamic because in the future there'll be more.

Comment: An ORDER BY may take between 50% and 75% of your request execution time, so try to avoid it as much as possible. Also as @Hybris95 mentionned, a clustered index may reduce the total time by up to 50% so be sure to create one.

Comment: But your result is just the latest row for each CODIGO+ARMAZEM combination and your `SALDO_ACUMULADO` is exactly the same as `MOV.SALDO + MOV.QUANTIDADE`

Comment: @dnoeth: You're right, maybe I was overthinking about it. Maybe I can use group by with these two columns, but how can I get just the last occurrence of each combination CODIGO+ARMAZEM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comments & expected result it seems like you simply want the latest row (= row with highest ID) for each `(CODIGO,ARMAZEM)` combination. And your `SALDO_ACUMULADO` calculation is exactly the same as `SALDO + QUANTIDADE`. This translates to a simple ROW_NUMBER:

```
WITH cte AS
 (
   SELECT 
      MOV.ID,
      MOV.DATA, MOV.CODIGO, MOV.ARMAZEM, MOV.TP_MOVI,
      MOV.SALDO,
      MOV.QUANTIDADE,
      MOV.SALDO + MOV.QUANTIDADE AS SALDO_ACUMULADO,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CODIGO, ARMAZEM ORDER BY MOV.ID DESC) AS rn
    FROM MOVIMENTACOES MOV
    WHERE DATA <= '2017-04-25 07:00:00'
 )
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your patience, it worked well! Just to be sure, I constantly have to correct some wrong input from the users. I've been doing that inserting a row with retroactive value on the column "DATA" and using a reprocess procedure in my software. To get the "right" value in this query, I just need to change the ORDER BY statement for `ORDER BY MOV.DATA DESC`?

Comment: @RafaelP: Yes, you need to to sort in a way that the row you want is on top. `ORDER BY MOV.DATA DESC` returns the latest row, in case you got multiple rows with the same timestamp you get one of them randomly (to avoid this you need to add another column to ORDER BY to make it unique)

Comment: Yes, I just put in the same timestamp here, but the real table has different timestamps. Thanks again bro! It worked really well!

Answer (score 3):

A computed column containing your calculated results may increase `SELECT` performances.

You may have to check for indexes and keys also.

I don't see any primary key for example, setting column `[ID]` as a primary key will help
It will create a `CLUSTERED INDEX` on it
(which will be used to decrease performance problems with `SELECT`).

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
I got some ideas in the comments, I'll try to do that.
In the context, I didn't put the ID as a primary key but in my current schema I've already did that and check for the indexes.